# Create end date based on max date within partition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table `Transactions` and it lacks an end date. I need to create an end date for date diff formulas in tableau.

DB table name = `[pursuant].[dbo].[transactions]`

Each record = a landlord with a status column and date that status started. Example: row 1 has landownerA with "Passed to Agent" status on 1/1/24. row 2 has landownerA with "Outreach" status on 1/22/24.

I need to create and end date based on [Date] column in table.

I want to turn this table into this:

[image]

Here is the code I tried using, but it's erroring out:

```
select 
    Landowner, Status, min(Date), max(Date)
from 
    (select 
         Transactions.*, 
         row_number() over (partition by Landowner, status order by Date) as seqnum
     from 
         Transactions t) t
group by 
    Landowner, Status, dateadd(day, - seqnum, Date)
order by 
    Landowner, min(Date);
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *windowed* `LEAD()` function to look ahead to the next start date for a given landowner, `DATEADD()` to subtract a day, and `ISNULL()` to handle to "no value" case.

Something like:

```
SELECT
    T.LandOwner,
    T.Comments,
    T.Status,
    T.Agent,
    T.Date as StartDate,
    ISNULL(
        DATEADD(day, -1,
            LEAD(T.Date) OVER(PARTITION BY T.LandOwner ORDER BY T.Date)
            ), 
        CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
    ) AS EndDate
FROM pursuant.dbo.Transactions T
```

Results:

| LandOwner | Comments | Status | Agent | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 85 Wilmigton LLC | Test 1 | Passed to Agent | Mike | 2024-01-05 | 2024-01-21 |
| 85 Wilmigton LLC | Test 2 | Outreach | Mike | 2024-01-22 | 2024-02-28 |
| Abe Holdings II LLC | Test 1 | Passed to Agent | Dan | 2024-01-08 | 2024-01-24 |
| Abe Holdings II LLC | Test 2 | Outreach | Dan | 2024-01-25 | 2024-02-28 |

See [this dv<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QwHMTKgj) for a demo.

Comment: `LEAD` is the same as `LAG` with the opposite ordering. I can't tell you for sure if it's more efficient either way, I feel like I read somewhere that `LAG` is better.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a simple LEAD function?

```sql
SELECT *
, ISNULL(DATEADD(DAY, -1, LEAD(Date) OVER(Partition BY Landowner ORDER BY Date)), GETDATE()) AS End_date
from Transactions t
```

By looking ahead one row, you can get the next start date, and then you just substract 1 day from it.

By wrapping in ISNULL, you handle the last transaction as well.

Comment: it seems to be pulling nulls for all of the original columns, then creating an end date column with date 2/28/24 repeating for every row

Comment: I very much doubt it, but if you post some script with data perhaps it's possible to debug what's wrong. Note that you won't get correct result if you use LEAD inside a CROSS APPLY or similar